# NHibernate mapping. Set collection of joined-subclass declared elements and the where property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping, subclass, where-clause

I am working on a project where persisted data can be flagged for deletion, but remains in the database having a column (is_deleted) set to TRUE.

This works fine using the hibernate class mapping property "where" and adding where="is_deleted = 0" to the tags. But it fails when I declare a set of sub-class elements.

This simplified example uses the class "Car" containing  a member collection of class "Wheel" which inherits from the class "CarPart":

```
<class name="Car" where="is_deleted = 0">
  <id name="Identifier" column="car_id">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <set name="Wheels" lazy="true" where="is_deleted = 0">
    <key column="car_id" />
    <one-to-many class="Wheel" />
  </set>
</class>

<class name="CarPart" where="is_deleted = 0">
  <id name="Identifier" column="part_id">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="IsDeleted" />

  <joined-subclass name="Wheel" >
    <key column="part_id" />
    <property name="radius" />
  </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

If I in code try to access the collection ***Car.Wheels*** I get an SQL error because the "where" clause applies to the table of the sub-class "Wheel" *instead* of its super-class "CarPart" where the IsDeleted property is actually defined.

The generated SQL looks similar to this:

```
select * from Wheel w inner join CarPart cp on...
where w.is_deleted = 0
```

rather than the correct

```
select * from Wheel w inner join CarPart cp on...
where cp.is_deleted = 0
```

- Is this a bug? Or am I missing a
  detail? The super-class CarPart
  already has where="is_deleted = 0",
  so logically this should apply to all
  defined sub-classes?
- Are there other methods of adding a
  is_deleted flag to all persisted data
  in NHibernate?

Your help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend creating a view for every soft delete table that filters out the deleted records and map the view in your domain model. Do this will make mapping much easier.

If your database supports it, you can create an INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger on the tables to set the is_deleted flag instead of deleting the record. That combined with views allows your domain model to completely ignore soft deletes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, though a major architecture change is not possible now.
What does work, and is 99% clean, is to have the is_deleted column mapped to the subclass instead (Wheel.IsDeleted rather than CarPart.IsDeleted).
This however means that the CarPart table does not store the info if a sub-class instance of Wheel (or other sub-classes) is deleted or not which would be the ideal.

If you fetch all CarParts you will get deleted instances as well, unfortunaltely.
If you fetch all Wheels you will only get where is_delete = 0, which is acceptable.

Comment: I'm still hoping someone can shed some light on this. I think the actual problem is that the where clause is pure SQL. To implement what I want would require the where clause to be HQL, which would be better in anyway imo.